# How to pattern match a tuple of Option with defined type in Java with Vavr

Tags: java, pattern-matching, vavr

new Vavr user here.
I am trying to pattern match a tuple of options to execute a statements if both of them are Some, in Scala I would have done this with:

```
val maybeThis: Option[String] = ???
val maybeThat: Option[String] = ???

(maybeThis, maybeThat) match {
  case (Some(dis), Some(that)) => ???
  case _ => ???
}
```

In Java, I am trying this approach:

```
Tuple2<Option<String>, Option<String>> tuple = new Tuple2<>(Option.of(...), Option.of(...));

return Match(tuple).of(
  Case($Tuple2($Some($(instanceOf(String.class))), $Some($(instanceOf(String.class)))),
                    (someThis, someThat) -> methodWhichEatsTwoStrings(someThis.get(), someThat.get())),
  Case($(), t -> run(() -> {
                throw new NullPointerException(...);
            })));
```

However, with this implementation the compiler complains that it was expecting `Some<Object>` instead of `Some<String>`, same error happens if I omit the `$(instanceOf(String.class)` in the pattern.

I am moderately sure this is merely a problem of proper syntax, yet I am struggling to find the correct documentation.
Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a vavr API construct called *for comprehension* that tries to mimic Scala's for comprehensions to the extent that it's possible to do in Java. With that construct you could solve your problem quite elegantly. See the [For overload for handling two Options](https://www.javadoc.io/static/io.vavr/vavr/1.0.0-alpha-3/io/vavr/API.html#For(io.vavr.control.Option,io.vavr.control.Option)) for more details. Here's an example code snippet:

```
String methodWhichEatsTwoStrings(String v1, String v2) {
    return v1 + v2; //combine the two values in some way
}

...

Option<String> option1 = Option.some("value1");
Option<String> option2 = Option.some("value2");

String combined = For(option1, option2)
    .yield((v1, v2) -> methodWhichEatsTwoStrings(v1, v2))
    .getOrElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("reasons"));
```

Of course, you could use `Option` wrapping values of different types for `option1` and `option2`, or combine multiple options, not just two. You could also use a different type for the return value of the `yield` function as well. I used `String` everywhere for the sake of simplicity and to conform to your original example.

I would like to add that I would try to avoid throwing `NullPointerException` in case one or both of the options are empty. Maybe try to use another vavr data type like `Either` to represent such an error case?